# verify the first digit of input is a 4

Tags: python, function

I have been given a string of digits and I must create a function that verifies if the first number in the string is equal to 4.

```
def verify(number) : 
  int (input[0],10)
  for number in input:
    if input [0] == 4:
      return True
    elif input [0] != 4:
      return False

input = "5000-0000-0000"
```

The result should be false but should print true if I change the input to 4000-0000-0000

Comment: Half of your code makes no sense, but what exactly is your question?

Comment: I think @Michelle just wants to know if the input starts with 4

Comment: @MarsNebulaSoup That would be a yes/no question then, not a programming question. Besides, she already knows whether the input starts with 4.

Answer (score 0):

Here, this should work:

```
def verify(number):
    number = str(number)
    if number.startswith("4"):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

It takes the var *number*, converts it to a string, checks if it starts with "4", and if it does, it returns true, otherwise it returns false.

```
def verify(number):
    number = str(number)               #convert number to string
    if number.startswith("4"):         #check if it starts with 4
        return True                    # return True if it does
    else:
        return False                   #otherwise return false
```

**EDIT:**

As @melpomene suggested, this code can be further simplified:

```
def verify(number):
    return str(number).startswith("4")
```

Comment: `if X: return True; else: return False` is equivalent to just `return X`.

Comment: Yes but it is more readable this way and it doesn't return anything otherwise

Comment: What do you mean, doesn't return anything? Your function can be simplified to `def verify(number): return number.startswith("4")`.

Comment: https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TaEstSgzrVIjrzQ3KbVI04pLAQiKUktKi/IUIGJ6xSWJRSXF5ZklGRpKJkqaXFwFRZl5JRpQjUomlpYW5hbmSpqaaBLGxkZA5Zr//wMA

Comment: @MarsNebulaSoup You are passing in an `int`, not a `str`. Still, you can simplify it to `def verify(number): return str(number).startswith("4")`

Comment: @melpomene Ok, I thought you were talking about my code, not your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You should compare to the string `"4"`. Also, comparison returns a Boolean anyway, so you can get rid of the `if` statements:

```
def verify(number):
    if not number:
        return False
    return number[0] == "4"
```

Note that you should check the length of the string with `not number` to avoid errors when an empty string is passed. Another option is `startswith`:

```
def verify(number):
    return number.startswith("4")
```

In this case, a check is not needed. However, this approach tends to be a bit slower because `startswith` is a more complex operation than a simple comparison.

Comment: Alternatively: `return number and number[0] == '4'`, though it's not necessarily more intuitive / readable.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to verify the exact pattern but starting with 4 then something like this:

```
def verify(s) :
  from re import match
  if match('^4[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{4}$',s): return True
  return False

print(verify("5000-0000-0000"))
print(verify("4000-0000-0000"))
```

or as was pointed out in the comments:

`if match('^4\d{3}\-\d{4}\-\d{4}$',s): return True`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to verify just one digit, write the following function:

```
def verify_number(text):
    has_4 = (text[0] == 4) 
    if has_4:
        return True
    return False

>>> verify_number("5000-0000-0000")
False

>>> verify_number("4000-0000-0000")
True
```

If you want to create a more generalizing function, which identifies if the first character is equal to any number (0-9), just do:

```
def verify_number(text, number):
    has_n = (text[0] == number) 
    if has_n:
        return True
    return False

>>> verify_number("5000-0000-0000", "5")
True

>>> verify_number("4000-0000-0000", "4")
True
```